# Unable to Connect Private Git Repository to Heroku

Tags: git, github, heroku, deployment, authorization

I recently tried to connect one of my private git repositories to Heroku App, When connection the app to the Github repository. It threw an error as given below,
[image: Heroku Error while connecting the private repository]
However, I double-checked the webhook for Heroku on Git Repository, There is webhook enabled for Heroku and the account linked to Heroku has administrative rights, See the below screenshot,
[image: Github Webhook for Heroku Server] 
I noticed the error is about authorization key. is it related to `ssh` key of my git repo? or I need to create deploy key?

Comment: Does the GitHub account you authenticated with in Heroku have admin access to the repository?

Comment: Yup, The account linked with Heroku has admin access to the repository.

Comment: Did you also try to reconnect the GitHub repository?

Comment: @rufer7 I tried around 7 to 8 time, but this it's the same error.

Comment: Is the account you authenticated with in Heroku really listed with "Admin" permissions under repository Settings > Collaborators & teams?

Comment: It's a repository owner account itself.

Comment: Did you try to explicitly add the account as Admin under Collaborators & teams? Probably it helps

Comment: I think that's a bad idea, I tried it when I was a newbie to Git, it said the owner could not be added as a collaborator in the repository.